# Really confused with this numpy shape mismatch error

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I was implementing a simple k-nearest-neighbor algorithm from sklearn on google cloud platform ml engine.  I used a custom metric to calculate the distance between two input vectors so that the distance is the weighted sum of elements in the element-wise squared difference between two vectors.  The code is below:

```
import os.path
from sklearn import neighbors
import numpy as np
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io

flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_string('input_dir', 'input', 'Input Directory.')
flags.DEFINE_string('input_train_data','train_data','Input Training Data File Name.')
pickle_file = os.path.join(FLAGS.input_dir, FLAGS.input_train_data)

def mydist(x, y):
    return np.dot((x - y) ** 2, weight)

with file_io.FileIO(pickle_file, 'r') as f:
    save = pickle.load(f)
    train_dataset, train_labels, valid_dataset, valid_labels = save['train_dataset'], save['train_labels'], save[
        'valid_dataset'], save['valid_labels']

train_data = train_dataset[:1000]
train_label = train_labels[:1000]
test_data = valid_dataset[:100]
weight = [1.0]* len(train_dataset[1])
knn = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(weights='distance', n_neighbors=20, metric=lambda x, y: mydist(x, y))
knn.fit(train_data, train_label)
predict = knn.predict(test_data)
print(predict)
```

train_dataset is a numpy array of shape (86667,13) and valid_dataset has shape (8000,13).  Train_labels has shape (86667,1) and valid_labels (8000,1).  For some reason I got a dimension mismatch:

```
line 15, in mydist return np.dot((x - y) ** 2, weight) ValueError: shapes 
(10,) and (13,) not aligned: 10 (dim 0) != 13 (dim 0)
```

Both x and y in the input of the custom metric should have size 13 yet somehow they have size 10.  Can anyone explain what is wrong here?

Comment: What is the shape of 'weight'? Also I am not familiar with the KNeighborRegressor function but where do you specify what x and y are?

Comment: weight is a list with length 13.  I put the custom metric function mydist in the metric argument in the instantiation of the KNeighborsRegressor.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the distance between the wrong terms. You cannot take the distance between the labels and the train features. These are of two different dimensions. You need to calculate the distance between any two feature points say x1 and x2, **not between the label and it's feature point (say x1 and y1)**. Secondly, when declaring the KNeighborsRegressor object, you have specified the parameter incorrectly. In the 'metric' parameter you specify the 'string' or the 'DistanceMetric' Object. **First you have to make a distance metric object and then pass it as metric**. So, this is the correct way of calling your function:

```
my_metric=DistanceMetric.get_metric('myfunc',func=mydist)
knn = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(weights='distance', n_neighbors=20, metric='myfunc')
```

Sklearn will itself take care of how the parameters are to be passed in the distance function. I am assuming that the weights variable is global for your code to function correctly.

Comment: So how should I modify my custom metric function in order to calculate the weighted element-wise squared difference between two input x1, x2?

Comment: I think your custom metric definition is correct. You only need to change to make it into a DistanceMetric object like the example shown above and pass it into the KNeighborsRegressor Object .